# I have to attend UCLH coming from Hitchin. Which is quickest, St Pancras to Warren St Stan or Finsbury Park on Northern line?

Tags: public-transport, london

I have to attend UCLH and I am travelling from Hitchin to Finsbury Park or st Pancras Stations.  my question is which would be the best route, get off at Finsbury Park and get on the Northern line to Warren Street OR get off at St Pancras and catch the Victoria line underground?

Comment: What's UCLH? Where is it? There are plenty of people who'll know the answer to this but will bother to Google to find out what you're even asking? (Also, did you try asking Google Maps what the fastest way is? It's usually pretty accurate.) It may also make a difference when you're travelling. For example, ordinarily, I'd expect say, the fast train from Cambridge (stops at Hitchin and Finsbury Park but nowhere between FP and King's Cross) to be faster than the tube between Finsbury Park and the King's Cross area.

Comment: If you get off at Finsbury Park to take the Northern Line you'll be waiting a while, because it's not on the Northern.  FPK is on the Piccadilly and Victoria lines.

Comment: @Roy Turner Hi, welcome to Travel.SE. You didn't state your purpose to attend UCLH, so I am making no assumptions here and an compelled to ask, "**do you have any mobility requirements**"? Answers obviously differ.

Comment: Easiest thing is to get on the first fast train to London, either to Kings Cross (KGX) or St Pancras (STP), and then it's about a 7-10 minute walk from either of those stations. When heading back to Hitchin check https://traintimes.org.uk/kings+cross/hitchin/ to see if the next fast train is from STP or KGX.

Answer (score 1):

The journey from Finsbury Park (FPK) to University College Hospital is so short that the main factors influencing time are likely to be how close you are to the stairs at FPK when you get off the train, how fast you can walk down the stairs, whether you walk down the escalator at King's Cross (KGX) so I think any of the usual on-line sources is going to be heavily influenced by assumptions they make. (You also have the option if you go to KGX of getting the tube to Euston Square which is likely to take about the same time.) So my conclusion is, it is unlikely to make much difference.

Coming back I would suggest routing via KGX as if you try to get on the train at FPK you are less likely to get a seat especially in the rush hour.